# Не работают точки остановки в Visual Studio проекте CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

[image]

Для сборки используется CMake с компилятором GCC.

**CMakePresets.json**

```
{
"version": 3,
"configurePresets": [
  {
    "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
    "cacheVariables": {
      "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "gcc.exe",
      "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "g++.exe"
    },
    "condition": {
      "type": "equals",
      "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
      "rhs": "Windows"
    },
    "generator": "Ninja",
    "hidden": true,
    "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
    "name": "windows-base"
  },
    {
        "name": "x64-debug",
        "displayName": "x64 Debug",
        "inherits": "windows-base",
        "architecture": {
            "value": "x64",
            "strategy": "external",
        },
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
        }
    }, < -- collapsed -- >
```

Если использовать cl.exe, отладка будет работать должным образом

Comment: Правильно, компилятор gcc не создает отладочных символов pdb.

Comment: @user7860670 а, точно, спасибо